# Update datatable using an array of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have an array of objects below.

```
   var arrayObjects= [
    {
        "name":       "Tiger Nixon",
        "position":   "System Architect",
        "salary":     "$3,120",
        "start_date": "2011/04/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "5421"
    },
    {
        "name":       "Garrett Winters",
        "position":   "Director",
        "salary":     "$5,300",
        "start_date": "2011/07/25",
        "office":     "Edinburgh",
        "extn":       "8422"
    }
]
```

The array is dynamically updated, through some API calls that my app makes.

I instantiate a datatable as shown.The array at this point, the arrayObjects is empty.

```
HTML
<table id="myTable" class="table table-striped table-dark">
         <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
              <th>Office</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
JAVASCRIPT
var myDataTable=$('#myTable').DataTable( {
    data: arrayObjects,
    columns: [
         { data: 'name' },
         { data: 'position' },
         { data: 'salary' },
         { data: 'office' }
    ]
} );
```

I add new objects in the array as follows:

**EDIT**: somedata can be as follows:

```
var somedata = {
        "name":       "James",
        "position":   "CEO",
        "salary":     "$13,140",
        "start_date": "2017/04/25",
        "office":     "London",
        "extn":       "54211"
    }
arrayObjects.push(somedata);
```

How do I add data to the table/update the table after that?
I have tried:

```
myDataTable.clear().row.add(arrayObjects).draw();
```

but it doesn't seem to work. The Table is still empty.

Comment: from where are you getting `somedata`?

Comment: Adding a row means passing one row of data each time. When you push `someData` to array,  also add as row then call draw after all rows added

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal I have updated the question to be bit clear, I hope that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in using `row` API instead of `rows` API because you are storing as an array of objects.

Change it to

```
myDataTable.clear().rows.add(arrayObjects).draw();
```

Working [jsfiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/prashant_pokhriyal/33jg20b4)

---

To work with `row` API you have to change the `arrayObjects` either as a simple array or single object like below

```
var arrayObjects = ['James', 'CEO', '$13000', 'London'];
// or
var arrayObjects = {
  "name": "James",
  "position": "CEO",
  "salary": "$13,140",
  "office": "London"
};

// it will work now
myDataTable.clear().row.add(arrayObjects).draw();
```